# could not load type from assembly yellow page error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

[image]

I replaced my Business Login (.dll) and .aspx page three or four times but I am getting the same error. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: see similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error

Comment: How did you replace your Business Login dll and aspx page? Did you just copy and paste to override or recompile and redeploy the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options here:

1. The new dll is in your **bin** directory and your web.config should not include, version, culture and PublicKeyToken details.
   or
2. Your new dll is the **GAC** (C:\Windows\Assembly) and your web.config should contain at least a valid PublicKeyToken.