# Why does using static field of type ImmutableArray in struct cause TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-studio-2015, immutablearray

I'm attempting to use a static field of type `ImmutableArray<T>` in a struct where `T` is the type of the struct. However, when I attempt to do this, I get an immediate `TypeLoadException` when I execute the program. This appears to occur before the program itself even begins to run. There is no stack trace available and I can't step through anything. Here is a simple example that illustrates the problem:

```
namespace Alpha
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Immutable;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var simple = new Simple(0);
            Console.WriteLine(simple.Index);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public struct Simple
        {
            public static readonly ImmutableArray<Simple> Values =
                ImmutableArray<Simple>.Empty;

            public Simple(int index)
            {
                Index = index;
            }

            public int Index { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error code I get:
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load type 'Alpha.Program+Simple' from assembly 'Alpha, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

If I don't initialize the field by removing the `ImmutableArray<Simple>.Empty` it still fails to run. However, if I change the static field to either of the following, the program runs just fine:

```
public static readonly ImmutableList<Simple> Values = ImmutableList<Simple>.Empty;  
public static readonly Simple[] Values = new Simple[0];
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and System.Collections.Immutable Version 1.1.37.

Comment: Due to **what exception**?

Comment: `TypeLoadException`, as stated in the question.

Comment: And what's the inner exception of `TypeLoadException`? And what's its message, stacktrace..

Comment: The message is "Could not load type XXX from assembly...".  The type is the struct containing the immutable array.  The exception is being thrown when I try to run a unit test and there is no stack trace.

Comment: You're very opaque. Why don't you paste the complete exception message as part of your question and any other info that may help us to provide you an answer?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, Sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult.  I've added a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this theread help a bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error

Comment: @sharpener, I checked the GAC and my Alpha assembly, which I just built for this example, is not there.

Comment: I thought rather the Immutables, but I did some experiments (registering it, looking for conflicting versions), but still getting the exception, so unfortunately no usable hint...