# How do I use a static variable without messing up my unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop

I have a user class - snippet as below:

```
public class User
    {
        private int userID;
        private static int nextID = 99;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String fullName;

        public User()
        {
        }

        public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password)
        {
            userID = nextID + 1;
            nextID++;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }
```

I want to give users a unique UserID that increments each time a user is instantiated.

I tried doing this with a static int NextID to hold the UserID of the next object and increment it in the constructor after it is used each time.

However, when I tried this, it messed up my unit tests and some of them fail when I Run All Tests but they all still pass when run individually.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this goal without messing up my unit tests?

Comment: What does "messing up my unit tests" really mean? What do your unit tests do exactly? How do your unit tests fail precisely? Is your coffee still hot, or already cooled down? Nothing but questions... ;)

Comment: Sorry, this is my code after editing back to not use nextID. Originally I had private int userID; and private static int nextID = 99; and then inside the constructor, I had userID = nextID + 1; and nextID++;

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry, that was a bit unclear. After introducing the static int, some of my unit tests fail when I Run All Tests but each of them pass when run individually

Comment: The tests should be independent, so it shouldn't matter if they have the same id or not. If the same ID causes an issue, they collide somewhere, which shouldn't happen at all. The tests do not run concurrently if they are part of the same Test class (or you told them explicitly), so this shouldn't be a concurrency problem.

Comment: Why not create an identity on SQL when saving a new record..?

Comment: Post your test class.

Comment: @DrewAguirre I will be creating a temporary xml data store for this sprint before creating any database in another sprint. Mardoxx I have several tests, they would be too long to post. I'm going to try Nkosi's solution below as I already have an interface pretty much the same as IUserFactory

Comment: @MichaelHennigan Okay Sorry about that... I thought you are saving the data directly to database. happy that your question is answered already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a design issue.

For example, try separating the concerns of the classes involved.

```
public interface IUserIdManager {
    int GetNextId();
}

public interface IUserFactory {
    User Create();
    User Create(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password);
}
```

Have the user manager implementation depend on the id manager to be used when creating instances.

```
public class UserFactory : IUserFactory {
    private readonly IUserIdManager ids;
    public UserFactory(IUserIdManager ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    public User Create() { 
        var user = new User();
        user.UserId = ids.GetNextId();
        return user;
    }

    public User Create(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) { 
        var user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password);
        user.UserId = ids.GetNextId();
        return user;
    }
}
```

The user class should not be concerned with creating its own id. That is not its responsibility. It should be kept lean as a simple POCO/model to hold data.

Comment: This is clearly a cleaner solution but probably won't solve the OP's issue. If it's a concurrency issue, then the IUserIdManager needs to be thread safe for, but this shouldn't happen in unit tests at all, as they need to be independent of each other.
I think the OP still hasn't posted the critical code, which is responsible for this.

Comment: @Zenima, This question arises from a previous question. My belief is that with the previous design assertions were failing as the expected and actual ids generated were not matching because of the static id being incremented.

Comment: @Zenima Yeah, I'm pretty sure now that the static id was the problem. In the above solution, what would the GetNextId() implementation look like? It is the generation of the user ID incremented by 1 each time that I am really struggling with

Comment: @MichaelHennigan same way you had it in the User class. when ever the method is called you increment the value and return that. The example was just meant to demonstrate how to design for flexibility. by having the abstraction you can now test in isolation without affecting other tests.

Comment: @MichaelHennigan `UserIdManager` should simply define a (non-static) int field, and the `GetNextId` simply calls `Interlocked.Increment(ref userId);`

If the issue was caused by concurrency, this will solve it, but I'm still skeptical.

Comment: Massive over complication!! He is doing, presumably, integrarion tests and needs each user id to be unique simulating the database. Will need to see test classes to see qhat the problem really is..

Comment: @Mardoxx I completey disagree. The original design was violating the Single Responsibility Principle by having a POCO class that should just hold data be responsible for generating its own id values. The answer combined with Zenima's comment is the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my production code, based on solution in Answer from @Nkosi above, here. Have given @Nkosi the credit for answering the question but just wanted to show the solution code and say that it worked. Also, thanks for all the comments everyone, it really helped me a lot!

```
public class UserIDGenerator : IUserIDGenerator
{
    private int nextUserID = 100;

    public int getNextUserID()
    {
        return nextUserID++;
    }
}

public class UserAdministration : IUserAdministration
{
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();

    private IUserIDGenerator userIDGenerator;

    public UserAdministration(IUserIDGenerator userIDGenerator)
    {
        this.userIDGenerator = userIDGenerator;
    }

    public bool addUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password)
    {
        users.Add(new User(userIDGenerator.getNextUserID(), firstName, lastName, email, password));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still isn't thread safe by the way. If you want to make it thread safe just look at Zenima's comment on the other answer.