# TFS: "Could not load type ' ' from assembly" - but only shows sometimes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, types, assemblies

In my solution, I run my unit tests and they all pass. When I then commit via TFS then sometimes the following shows in the TFS build step regarding one of the projects:

```
Could not load type 'Castle.Proxies.HttpContextProxy' from assembly
'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=xxx'
```

Why is the error only showing sometimes?

I've checked all the Assembly Names under 'Application' tab of properties in VS as suggested in
 "[Could not load type from assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error)" - also tried to clear my bin-folder, but nothing happens - still errors show occassionaly in the tfs-build steps for one of the projects unit test (which again never shows in VS17).

Comment: occasional errors are the worst.  I assume you have installed castle on the build server? Do you have is as a nuget package in your solution that might make it available always.