# Rerun successful build-step on TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control, automated-tests, pull-request

According to [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702178/tfs-could-not-load-type-from-assembly-but-only-shows-sometimes) I have a test that sporadically fails in tfs, which means that one of the build-steps sometimes fails.

The build step maybe fails every 10th to 20th time it is run.

I am therefore wondering, if there is a simple way to rerun successful build steps on tfs?

Comment: I'm not fully understand, if the test will fail so you want to re-run the build automatically?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No, I would like to re-run the successful build-step again and again n-times and hopefully not fail. If it fails, I will again have to make some changes and then make a new commit.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk a simple way is to fx place a space in the code and make a new commit, but that will force all the build steps to run again and will mean a lot of non-productive time spend, I think.

Comment: Now I understand :) interesting request... I can think about a powershell script with many lines of msbuild, what do you think?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No need, but thanks. Also there are some good tutorials for that online, so I should just be not-lazy, but if they had a rerun-button or something that simple, that would be great in my situation. Just wondered if anyone else had the same issue and found an easy workaround :)

Comment: There is no re-run button for one step, I don't think there is a feature to achieve that. an easy workaround can be powershell script with loop for msbuild, do you want an example?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk If you have an example by hand / link, then yes, please.

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: If a test sporadically fails **fix or remove the test**. A test that isn't a consistent indicator is actively detrimental to your codebase.

Comment: @DanielMann I agree. I 'fixed' it and therefore had to figure a way to re-run the buildstep/tests on tfs n-times to see if I could count on the new fix or if that also failed sporadically. But of course a sporadically failing test needs attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a feature to run a task `n` times, but here a workaround to run the build many times (PowerShell script):

```
$times = 30
For ($i=1; $i =lt $times; $i++) {

    Write-Host "*** Start to build $i time ***"
    # I use VS 2019 Enterprise, change the path if you have another version
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Currnet\Bin"
    # Change the folder/sub folder to your solution path
   ./msbuild.exe "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\{your soultion name}.sln"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great - thanks. It's running and giving a nice status back with no errors. The build steps don't affect my tfs though, but should the outcome not be the same anyway? So if running the script 30 times for example, and I do not get any errors, should I then presume/trust, that it also goes for my tfs-build-steps?

Comment: I don't know exactly why you build step fail, you just need to run it a few times and check i you can trust it..