# ElasticSearch Nest exception (Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException) when trying to do an index (Nest 7.12.0)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have integrated a series of ElasticSearch Nest code into our own solution file. Before I did this, I have it tested first in a separate solution. In my separate solution everything works fine.

The details of the exception is:

```
Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: The type initializer for 'Nest.JsonNetSerializer.Converters.HandleNestTypesOnSourceJsonConverter' threw an exception.
```

Upon checking the debug messages, here are some more details I got.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Nest.CartesianPoint' from assembly 'Nest, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx'.
   at Nest.JsonNetSerializer.Converters.HandleNestTypesOnSourceJsonConverter..cctor()
```

I've been googling around and I could not find a specific answer to this. All I can find is somehow my problem is kind of related to this since in my separate test code I do not have any of this exception - [Could not load type from assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error)

To give some details, this is how I create my client.

```
private ElasticClient GetClient()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, (builtin, settings) =>
                new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings, () =>
                   new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                                                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
                                              }
                   )).DefaultIndex(DefaultIndex);
    return new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
}
```

Right now I'm looking into our solution files with this solution - [Could not load type from assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124841/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-error) - in mind to resolve this.

I'm hoping that someone might have encountered this before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was another instance of Nest and Elastic search in one of the projects and the problem was resolved by updating all with the same, latest version of Nest and Elastic.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted. Nest and Nest.JsonNetSerializer packages need to be the same version