# Resharper: Inconclusive: Exit code is 14942211 in another test

Tags: resharper, specflow

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and latest Resharper. I have Nunit3 installed along with test adapters. I keep on getting this error. Can someone help me on this

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbcPH.png]

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Please [edit] your question to include enough information for a [repro]. Offhand, the test is neither failing, nor passing. it is inconclusive just like the test results say. Please post the gherkin scenario and the step definitions.

Comment: I solved it by removing all bins and recompiling all from MSBuild command line outside VS, then restarting VS

Answer (score 3):

I got the problem. If your test projects are using the SDK project style.

You should add this code into your csprj file.

```
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>     <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

If your test project app.config file:

1. The app.config contains only binding redirects, you can delete the entire file
2. The app.config contains setting, you should delete the  binding redirects parts

Comment: Cool! This fix saved our day!! It seems that we somehow got conflicted references to nunit.

Answer (score 0):

Check you App.config file - maybe some dependencies are corrupted.

I just had the same issue, and it turned out that the runtime section in App.config had two nested assemblyBinding tags. I fixed that, and the error disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was using an old Version of FakeItEasy(3.3.2) or RhinoMock together with Nunit3. Upgrading to a recent version solved that error for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because the test assembly has the same exact name as the assembly under test.

I scaled down my test assembly to only 1 test case, and then a different error appeared-- [cannot load from type exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784297/3834). That pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are valuable, however in my case there was [TestFixture] attribute in some base class, which don't had any tests inside. Removing this redundant attribute helped to solve the "inconclusive" issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the NUnit test adapter not being able to properly resolve the tested DLL and/or its dependencies.

In addition to the other answers, here is what you can also check (that was the case for my own trouble with exit code 14942211):

In your .csproj file, project references might have `<Private>False</Private>` tag. Change all of them to `<Private>True</Private>` (or add this tag to each reference that doesn't have it). For me, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package is required for this to work. Install it via `dotnet` CLI or Visual Studio UI.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit